# How to implement non-static method in a static class?

Tags: java

Is there a way to implement `wait();` (non-static method) in a static context. For example:

```
public static void getkeylist(List keylist){
   for (int i=0;i<keylist.size();i++){
         System.out.println(keylist.get(i));
         wait(1000);   
   }
}
```

I am getting an error "Non-static method wait(long) cannot be referred from static context."

Please help me to solve my problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can only `wait` on something you are `synchronized` on.  What are you synchronized on?  The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait) says "throws IllegalMonitorStateException - if the current thread is not the owner of the object's monitor."

Comment: Beware of loops: `Call to 'Thread.sleep()' in a loop, probably busy-waiting.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about `Thread.sleep(1000);`

`wait` is really used for thread control, along with `notify`. I think you're confused between the method names.

Comment: _Thank you very much. I tried Thread.sleep(1000) it works but it requires throw InterruptedException. Thanks_

Answer (score 1):

suppose your class is call Foo, you can call `Foo.class.wait(1000)`, or alternatively you can define a static object and call wait method on it:

```
private static final Object lock = new Object();
...

lock.wait();
```

Comment: You need to hold the monitor of the object you are calling `wait` on, so you need to have `synchronized(lock) { ... lock.wait(); }`. I wouldn't recommend locking a `Class` object because anyone can obtain a lock on it without your knowledge, likely to result in deadlock.

Comment: @CameronSkinner definitely with you on sync block and locking class points.

Answer (score 0):

Create non static method class object and used it.

```
.....
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.wait();
.....
```

Comment: Doing that will cease the current thread forever because no thread is able to wake up `foo`